# strapi public access settings on collections

Tags: strapi

I have strapi v4.0.4 installed, and I created som collections and under settings/USERS & PERMISSIONS PLUGIN/Roles/Public

I set the public users to access find, and find one.
But even with these settings saved, when I try to access a collection called service on: http://localhost:1337/services I get the error of 404, not found.

I have the same db running on v3 with the same settings on that collection and there is no problem getting all the data.
Anyone who knows what the issue could be?

Answer (score 1):

I got some advice from discord community,

If I have a collection called services, I need to set the url to: http://localhost:1337/api/services